# Inertia.JS reload props after post request

Tags: laravel, vue.js, vuejs3, inertiajs

I am currently pretty confused why Inertia.js is not reloading or rerendering my page.

I have a form that could be filled, once submitting this will execute:

```
Inertia.post("/ban", ban);
```

This will redirect to a POST in the web.php of my Laravel.
That looks like this:

```
Route::post("/ban", [Speler::class, "ban"]);
```

This redirects to a class called "Speler", in there is a function called "ban".
Once done some SQL statements it will execute this return:

```
return Redirect::route("speler", [$steam])->with("success", "Ban doorgevoerd!");
```

This will go back to the web.php, and go to the route speler with the session data "success".
That redirect goes into the web.php:

```
Route::get("/speler/{steam}", [PageLoader::class, "speler"])->name("speler");
```

This one goes to the PageLoader controller, and execute the "speler" function.

But here it gets weird, this will return a Inertia::render of the same page the person was on, but would need to add another prop, or change the prop. *(so i can show a popup with te text that it succeeded)*

```
return Inertia::render("Panel/Speler",
                ["steamNaam" => $steamNaam, "discord" => $discord, "karakterAantal" => $karakterAantal, "karakters" => $karakters, "sancties" => $sanctiesReturn, "punten" => $aantalPunten, "steamid" => $steamid, "success" => $melding]
            );
```

The "success" prop contains $melding that simply contains a string.

But for some reason it doesn't seem to re-render the page, the form stays filled, and the props are the same.
Does someone have a solution?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you setup your form with the [form helper](https://inertiajs.com/forms#form-helper), you can reset the form on a successful post like this:

```js
form.post('/ban', {
  preserveScroll: true,
  onSuccess: () => form.reset(), // reset form if everything went OK
})
```

The success message, which you set with

```php
return Redirect::route("speler", [$steam])->with("success", "Ban doorgevoerd!");
```

is usually taken care of by the Inertia middleware and made available as 'Shared data'. See [this docs page](https://inertiajs.com/shared-data#flash-messages) on how to configure that. Shared data is rendered in `$page.props` variable. That is where you can find the `Ban doorgevoerd!` message. You can show these to the user as follows:

```
<div v-if="$page.props.flash.message" class="alert">
    {{ $page.props.flash.message }}
</div>
```

Depending on your implementation, you would need to watch this property. See the [`FlashMessages` component](https://github.com/inertiajs/pingcrm/blob/master/resources/js/Shared/FlashMessages.vue) on the pingCRM demo app for an example implementation.

Comment: Thank you, exactly what I was looking for!